Adding BlazorBootstrap to a new Blazor project and showing a grid
Example attached.
Create a new Blazor Web App in VisualStudio 2022.
It is then unclear how to install BlazorBoorstrap because there is no index.html file.
However, it seems to work if you make the changes to App.razor instead.
Then, add a grid to Home.razor by copying from the example at https://demos.blazorbootstrap.com/grid to get:
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<h1>Grid</h1>

@code {
    public class Employee1
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Designation { get; set; }
        public DateOnly DOJ { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    }
}

<p>Where&rsquo;s the grid?</p>

<Grid TItem="Employee1"
      Class="table table-hover table-bordered table-striped"
      DataProvider="EmployeesDataProvider"
      AllowFiltering="true"
      AllowPaging="true"
      PageSize="5"
      AllowSorting="true"
      AllowSelection="true"
      SelectionMode="GridSelectionMode.Multiple"
      SelectedItemsChanged="OnSelectedItemsChanged"
      Responsive="true">

    <GridColumns>
        <GridColumn TItem="Employee1" HeaderText="Id" PropertyName="Id" SortKeySelector="item => item.Id">
            @context.Id
        </GridColumn>
        <GridColumn TItem="Employee1" HeaderText="Employee Name" PropertyName="Name" SortKeySelector="item => item.Name">
            @context.Name
        </GridColumn>
        <GridColumn TItem="Employee1" HeaderText="Designation" PropertyName="Designation" SortKeySelector="item => item.Designation">
            @context.Designation
        </GridColumn>
        <GridColumn TItem="Employee1" HeaderText="DOJ" PropertyName="DOJ" SortKeySelector="item => item.DOJ">
            @context.DOJ
        </GridColumn>
        <GridColumn TItem="Employee1" HeaderText="Active" PropertyName="IsActive" SortKeySelector="item => item.IsActive">
            @context.IsActive
        </GridColumn>
    </GridColumns>

</Grid>

<div class="mt-3">
    Total Items Count: @(employees?.Count.ToString() ?? "null")
</div>

<div class="mt-3">
    Selected Items Count: @selectedEmployees.Count
</div>

<div class="mt-2">
    Selected Employees:
    <ul>
        @foreach (var emp in selectedEmployees)
        {
            <li>@emp.Name</li>
        }
    </ul>
</div>

@code {
    private List<Employee1> employees = default!;

    private HashSet<Employee1> selectedEmployees = new();

    private async Task<GridDataProviderResult<Employee1>> EmployeesDataProvider(GridDataProviderRequest<Employee1> request)
    {
        if (employees is null) // pull employees only one time for client-side filtering, sorting, and paging
            employees = GetEmployees(); // call a service or an API to pull the employees

        return await Task.FromResult(request.ApplyTo(employees));
    }

    private List<Employee1> GetEmployees()
    {
        return new List<Employee1>
        {
            new Employee1 { Id = 107, Name = "Alice", Designation = "AI Engineer", DOJ = new DateOnly(1998, 11, 17), IsActive = true },
            new Employee1 { Id = 103, Name = "Bob", Designation = "Senior DevOps Engineer", DOJ = new DateOnly(1985, 1, 5), IsActive = true },
            new Employee1 { Id = 106, Name = "John", Designation = "Data Engineer", DOJ = new DateOnly(1995, 4, 17), IsActive = true },
            new Employee1 { Id = 104, Name = "Pop", Designation = "Associate Architect", DOJ = new DateOnly(1985, 6, 8), IsActive = false },
            new Employee1 { Id = 105, Name = "Ronald", Designation = "Senior Data Engineer", DOJ = new DateOnly(1991, 8, 23), IsActive = true },
            new Employee1 { Id = 102, Name = "Line", Designation = "Architect", DOJ = new DateOnly(1977, 1, 12), IsActive = true },
            new Employee1 { Id = 101, Name = "Daniel", Designation = "Architect", DOJ = new DateOnly(1977, 1, 12), IsActive = true },
            new Employee1 { Id = 113, Name = "Merlin", Designation = "Senior Consultant", DOJ = new DateOnly(1989, 10, 2), IsActive = true },
            new Employee1 { Id = 117, Name = "Sharna", Designation = "Data Analyst", DOJ = new DateOnly(1994, 5, 12), IsActive = true },
            new Employee1 { Id = 108, Name = "Zayne", Designation = "Data Analyst", DOJ = new DateOnly(1991, 1, 1), IsActive = true },
            new Employee1 { Id = 109, Name = "Isha", Designation = "App Maker", DOJ = new DateOnly(1996, 7, 1), IsActive = true },
            new Employee1 { Id = 111, Name = "Glenda", Designation = "Data Engineer", DOJ = new DateOnly(1994, 1, 12), IsActive = true },
        };
    }

    private Task OnSelectedItemsChanged(HashSet<Employee1> employees)
    {
        selectedEmployees = employees is not null && employees.Any() ? employees : new();
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}

The grid doesn't show.
I notice that a breakpoint in
 private async Task<GridDataProviderResult<Employee1>> EmployeesDataProvider(GridDataProviderRequest<Employee1> request)

does not get hit.
Any idea if/whether BlazorBootstrap grid can work?
Or is BlazorBootstrap just not a good way to do tables in Blazor?
What should I be using?

@richard-barraclough
Please check the following starter projects:


Interactive render mode: Auto (Server and WebAssembly)
Interactive location: Global
Starter project: Net8.BlazorAutoGlobal



Interactive render mode: Auto (Server and WebAssembly)
Interactive location: Per page/component
Starter project: Net8.BlazorAutoPerPage

Screenshot

Let us know if you need any help.
